# Add simple histogram to legend in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, legend

Given a `ggplot` plot generated using the following code

```
size = 10000
d = data.frame(
  type = rep(c("A","B","C"), each=size),
  val = c(rnorm(size, 0, 1), rnorm(size, 1, 2),rnorm(size, 2, 3))
)

require(ggplot2)
(
  ggplot(subset(d, is.element(type, c("A", "C"))), aes(x=val))
  + geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), bins=100, position="identity", alpha=0.5)
  + geom_line(aes(color=type), stat="density", size=1)
)
```

Is it possible to add a grey square with a custom label representing the simple histogram to the legend? Can it be done without [creating a dummy item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18155165/add-new-item-to-ggplot2-legend)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to put `fill=` into `aes()` for the `geom_histogram()` line.  You don't have a column in your dataset to assign to this, but if you assign `fill="string name"` in `aes()`, then `ggplot` will create a fill legend with that as the label.

Of course, the color will default to the `ggplot` "red" color, so if you want to go with gray again, you have to set that with `scale_fill_manual()`, since `fill=` outside `aes()` will overwrite anything you put within `aes()`.

```
ggplot(d, aes(x=val)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..density.., fill='histogram'),
    bins=100, position="identity", alpha=0.5) +
  geom_line(aes(color=type), stat="density", size=1) +
  scale_fill_manual(values='gray20')
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Is there any way to change the word `fill` in the legend to something else or remove it entirely?

Comment: Sure, just add that to the `name=` argument of `scale_fill_manual()`.  So `scale_fill_manual(name="My Legend Title", values="gray20")` would give you the same plot with the legend title changed.  To remove, you can just include `""`, but that will keep the line for the legend title, so to remove I would set `name=NULL`.